# php echo outputs only part of a variable in a form

Tags: php

I'm loading a variable from a database like:

```
$adres = $row['adres']; //(= "Hoge Filterweg")
```

Then using it in a echo like:

```
echo input type='text' name='adres' value='{$adres}'
```

It displays on the form only the first part of the adress ( "Hoge"), but not the whole adress.

What could I do now?

Comment: Show us your **full** and **real** code!

Comment: are you using smarty (or similar template engine) ?

Comment: That code will throw the error `Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''`., which isn't the behaviour you described. You need to produce [a test case that demonstrates your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes surrounding the inline variable like `value='{$adres}'` dit the trick.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need double quotes to pass params with space.
This code should help you:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"adres\" value=\"{$adres}\" />"
```

Comment: Not true. The string needs to be double quoted to interpolate variables at all, but there's no restriction on using single quotes inside it. http://note.io/1GNjTSc

Comment: @quentin i've just added the code which will help user to resolve it problem. I've added double quotes, since it is semantically better for html. I fully understand that there is no difference between double quote and single quote for echo html.

Comment: "i've just added the code which will help user to resolve it problem" — It doesn't address the problem at all (the code in the question has lots of issues but none of them would create the problem described, so the question is unanswerable). "I've added double quotes, since it is semantically better for html." — No, it isn't. Quotes have no impact on the semantics of HTML at all. "I fully understand that there is no difference between double quote and single quote for echo html." — That appears to contradict your previous sentence.